# django how to get count for manytomany field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have model for question:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

And I have model for answer:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ans_body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.ans_body
```

Question creation and answer submission are working perfectly. I cant correctly show answer for particular question. But when I try to get the count of answer for particular question its not showing. It displays 0 count.

In my view I am getting the list of the answer by:

```
context["question_list"] = Question.objects.all()
```

And in my template

```
{% for question in question_list %}
   {{ question.title }}
    Ans:{{question.answers.count}}
{% endfor %}
```

When I do this I get the count 0  if there are answers. How can I get the count of the answers for particular questions.

Answer (score 17):

This worked:

```
{{question.answer_set.count}}
```

Happy..

Comment: That works, but does not scale. It will query the database once for every single question returned. So if you have 1000 questions, you're launching 1000 queries in a single request just for this bit of data alone.

Comment: @Ivan Then what should be the correct way to get a count?

Comment: @yajantb See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150155/1868358 -- I don't know what issues the OP was having with it, but annotating a Count of the child objects from the parent model is the way to go.

Comment: @yajantb https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150155/1359986 -- annotate the entire queryset instead of doing this inline in a template, that way it's done in the first query instead of generating N queries, where N is the number of questions to render

Answer (score 16):

You can do something like `{{ question.answers.all.count }}`, but if you are iterating over more than question it will cause a database query for *every* question.

If you want to annotate the whole queryset with the count for each question:

```
from django.db.models import Count

context['question_list'] = Question.objects.all().annotate(
    answer_count=Count('answers')
)
```

Then you can access the count for each question with `{{ question.answer_count }}`.

Comment: There are few bugs opened related to Count annotation. In some cases 'distinct' solves them. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15049

Comment: it still dont show the count. if i select the answer and save the model from admin then it shows the count of the no of answer i have selected and saved in admin. whats wrong ??

Answer (score 6):

Why not use: `Question.objects.all().count()`

For my project, I have a Field in 'Info' Model

```
users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_likes", blank=True)
```

I use below code to count the number of like then show it in Admin List Page.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Info
class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'like_count',)
    def like_count(self, obj):
        return obj.users_like.all().count()

admin.site.register(Info, InfoAdmin)
```

The result is:
[image]
Hope these can help you!

Comment: Little missing - self argument in like_count function.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. +1

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you without any problem in your case:

```
{{question.answer_name.count}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely related to original question, but if you're getting the count just to check if there are records, this should be much faster as the dataset grows:

```
if question.answers.first() is not None
```