# How to exclude querysets that already has m2m relationship

Tags: django, forms, relationship

I'm creating a Model with a many2many relationship, if the other model has a parent it needs to be excluded from the form

I know how to exclude if I know the pk but it has to be for any relationship, I read the django official documentation and can't solve it yet

models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='Date_limit')

class GlobalInvoice(models.Model):
    date_limit = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name='Date Limit'
    )
    invoices = models.ManyToManyField(
        Invoice,
        verbose_name='Invoices'
    )
```

forms.py

```
class GlobalInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(
            invoice_created__lte=date.today()
        ) # the exclude should be here
        super(GlobalInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['invoices'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            label='Invoices:', 
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            queryset=invoices
        )
    class Meta:
        model = GlobalInvoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

If I create a new Global Invoice the Invoice field needs to exclude the Invoices that already has a Global Invoice assigned

Comment: Here's an answer which shows how to get the count of an m2m field in a query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150155/301377. You can then filter on the annotated field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class GlobalInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(
            invoice_created__lte=date.today()
        ) # the exclude should be here
        super(GlobalInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['invoices'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            label='Invoices:', 
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            queryset=invoices
        )
        self.fields['invoices'].queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(globalinvoice__isnull=True)
    class Meta:
        model = GlobalInvoice
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here I am using [**`reverse relation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/) for making the query. Also,  [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) allows me to find the Invoices which does not have relation with `GlobalInvoice`.