# Django Likes count not showing any changes in the Post

Tags: python, django

I have made a like class in the model for the posts made, so far I have reached that everything was working well but now when a new post I added there is no update although when I was progressing I worked well. Now it is just refreshing the page without adding the count.

I am not sure if the problem is related to the fact that I am trying to like a post in a list of posts view, not in a single post detailed view

Here is the Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def like_url(self):
        return reverse("score:like-toggle", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here are the Views:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'

class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all:
                obj.like.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.like.add(user)

        return url_
```

Here are the URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('/like/', PostLikeToggle.as_view(), name='like-toggle'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

Here is the template:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
        {% block content %}
        <div class='content_container'>
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="dcard">

                    <div class="post_image">
                        {% if post.design %}
                            <a href="{% url 'score:post-detail' post.id %}">
                            <img src="{{ post.design.url }}" alt="">
                            </a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center pb-0">

                        <div class="engagement">
                            <a href=""><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "likes">
                            Likes:{{ post.likes.all.count }}<a  href="{{ post.get_like_url }}">Like</a>
                        </div>

                        <h4 class="card-title"><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></h4>
                        <h5 class="blue-text pb-2">
                            <strong>
                                <a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}">{{ post.designer }}</a>
                            </strong>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endblock content %}
        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: post.likes.all.count, also consider count aggregation for better performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django how to get count for manytomany field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149984/django-how-to-get-count-for-manytomany-field)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't I tried everything, I am not sure whether it is the `pk` in urls and views

Comment: show us full template

Comment: I edited the question with the template