# How to retrieve the .count in a django template through ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, templates, count

I have some models, which are connected via ManyToMany or Foreignkey.

I would like to get  a **.count** value for
`tutor.students.lessons.type`
and display the number of lessons online or class based.

I have tried to pass in
`tuttype= tutorObj.students.get(type="CLASS")`
through the views
which does not get the required result

and have been trying out `{{tutorobj.students.type.ONLINE.get}}`
`{{tutorobj.students.get(type=ONLINE)}}` in the templates with no luck also

**models.py**

```
class Tutor(models.Model): 
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    students        = models.ManyToManyField('Student', blank=True)
    lessons         = models.ManyToManyField('Lesson', blank=True)
    lesson_reviews  = models.ManyToManyField('LessonNote', blank=True)
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id              = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, 
    editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    


class Student(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('F', 'Female',)
    )

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('CLASS', 'Class',),
        ('ONLINE', 'Online',)
    )

    YEAR_CHOICES = (
        ('K1', 'Kindergarten 1',),
        ('K2', 'Kindergarten 2',),
        ('K3', 'Kindergarten 3',),
        ('P1', 'Primary 1',),
        ('P2', 'Primary 2',),
        ('P3', 'Primary 3',),
        ('P4', 'Primary 4',),
        ('P5', 'Primary 5',),
        ('P6', 'Primary 6',),
        ('M1', 'Mathayom 1',),
        ('M2', 'Mathayom 2',),
        ('M3', 'Mathayom 3',),
        ('M4', 'Mathayom 4',),
        ('M5', 'Mathayom 5',),
        ('M6', 'Mathayom 6',),
        ('C', 'College',),
        ('U', 'University',),
        ('A', 'Adult',),
    )
    taught_by       = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
    editable=False)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    school_year     = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=YEAR_CHOICES, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    gender          = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    type            = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    hours_weekly    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField()
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id              = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, 
    editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            "name", "type"
        ]





class Lesson(models.Model):
    DAY_CHOICES         = (
        ('Mon', 'Monday',),
        ('Tues', 'Tuesday',),
        ('Wed', 'Wednesday',),
        ('Thur', 'Thursday',),
        ('Fri', 'Friday',),
        ('Sat', 'Saturday',),
        ('Sun', 'Sunday',),
    )
    
    headed_by           = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    after_class_note    = models.ForeignKey("LessonNote", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    day                 = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=DAY_CHOICES, null=True)
    start_time          = models.TimeField()
    student             = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True)
    created             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )
    id              = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, 
    editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.headed_by) + " / " + str(self.student) + " / " + str(self.day)

    class Meta:
        ordering=[
            'day', 'start_time', 'student'
        ]
```

views.py (view in question that needs the .count)

```
def tutor(request, pk):
    tutorObj = Tutor.objects.get(id=pk)
    tutor = Tutor.objects.all()
    students = Student.objects.all()
    
    context = {'students': students, "tutorobj": tutorObj, "tutor":tutor}
    return render(request, 'tutor.html',  context)
```

thank you in advance for your time in helping me.

Comment: Hi, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149984/django-how-to-get-count-for-manytomany-field), think it solves your issue - I would go with performing the query in your view and adding the results to the context to use it within the template.

Comment: im not sure about performing the query......

i have a tutor, located by id.
This tutor has a student, that has a type of lesson (ie online or class)
i need the count of the type of lesson. online and class respectivly.  

your answer helps if i wanted the students.count, whereas i need the lesson_type located in the students model, connected to the tutor.

    typecount= tutorObj.students.get(type="ONLINE")

Comment: Think the query would be something in the line of this:

`from django.db.models import Count`
`Tutor.objects.values('students__type').annotate(count=Count('students__type')).order_by('count')`


This should give a result like this: 
`[{'students__type': 'online', 'count': some_number}, {'students__type': 'class', 'count': some_number}]`

Comment: You are correct of course.
When Tutor.objects.values...... 
    <QuerySet [{'student__type': 'CLASS', 'count': 9}, {'student__type': None, 'count': 28}]>  is returned.....however, once I try to to the same with my instance of tutor tutorObj=Tutor.object.get(id=pk)
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Tutor instances is returned.

How would i find and display into my template the value for the specific tutor. 
also thank you for your time already.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the correct value by joining two filters together.

```
def home(request):
tutors = Tutor.objects.all()
tutor1online    = 
Lesson.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
1").filter(type__icontains="ONLINE")
tutor1class     = 
Lesson.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
1").filter(type__icontains="CLASS")
tutor2online    = 
Lesson.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
2").filter(type__icontains="ONLINE")
tutor2class     = 
Lesson.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
2").filter(type__icontains="CLASS")


context={'tutor2class':tutor2class, 'tutor2online': tutor2online, 
'tutor1class':tutor1class, 'tutor1online': tutor1online, 
'tutors':tutors}
return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

i pass it into the template with

```
{{tutor1online.count}}
```

this is not a dynamic way to render this information and i must be missing something simple, but it will have to do for now.

i would much prefer to locate the value whilst it is attached to an instance of the tutor, which is what i cannot understand.
i think i'll think of another way to ask this question again, as i am not even sure that i am asking the right question as of yet.